# Using \parbox in Beamer has unwanted effects

Tags: beamer, spacing, vertical-alignment

I want to change from an itemized list on one slide to an image on the next slide. I tried this with a `\parbox` with overlay specifications. It works ok when the inner position of the parbox is set to `c` but messes the alignment up when switched to `t`. I think the `t` option alignment is nicer so I would like to retain it.

**MWE:**

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Headline}
  Some text that is static
\parbox[c][.4\textheight][t]{\textwidth}{
    \begin{itemize}[<1>]
    \item{One}
    \item{Two}
  \end{itemize}
  \only<2>{Second slide\\ \includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{PerturbationPol}}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which results in the wrong spacing on the second slide.

[image: Wrong spacing]

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the `\parbox`.  You just need to move your overlay specification for the itemize putting the whole list in an `\only<1>`.  The first frame below should be as you request, the second demonstrates what happens with `\begin{itemize}<1>` even without the `\parbox`:

Frame 1 view 1

[image: Frame 1 view 1]

Frame 1 view 2

[image: Frame 1 view 2]

Frame 2 view 2

[image: Frame 2 view 1]

Frame 2 view 2

[image: Frame 2 view 2]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Headline}
  Some text that is static
  \parbox[t][.4\textheight][t]{\textwidth}{
  \only<1>{\begin{itemize}
    \item{One}
    \item{Two}
  \end{itemize}}
  \only<2>{Second slide\\ \includegraphics[width=.75\textwidth]{PerturbationPol}}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  Text
  \begin{itemize}[<1>]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \end{itemize}
  \begin{itemize}[<2>]
  \item Three
  \item Four
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```